# Generate random numbers from mixture and put outcome of each distribution in sequence

Tags: r, random, statistics

I want to put random numbers come from first gamma `[gamma with shape=2 , rate=4]` in vector 
and from second gamma `[gamma with shape=3 , rate=4]` in another vector

```r
x <- rep(0,20)
for (i in 1:20){
    U[i] <- runif(1,0,1)
    if( U[i] < 0.8){
        x[i] <- rgamma(1,shape=2,rate=4)
    } else { 
        x[i] <- rgamma(1,shape=3,rate=4)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try (if I got what you mean):

```
rgamma(20,shape=sample(2:3,20,replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.8,0.2)),rate=4)
```

Your `shape` is `sample`d from `2:3` with the 2 having 80% probability. Then you can call `rgamma` just once, since the vectorized nature of it.

If you need two distinct vectors, you can:

```
nShape2<-rbinom(1,20,.80)
vecShape2<-rgamma(nShape2,shape=2,rate=4)
vecShape3<-rgamma(20-nShape2,shape=3,rate=4)
```

Comment: I'm trying to find maximum likelihood estimator for distribution mixture of two gamma using newton raphson,using method of  moment as starting point for my algorithm  so i need to split  the values of two gamma to calculate 
rate= mean(x)/var(x)
shape1= mean(ranom number come from first gamma)^2/ var(ranom number come from first gamma)
shape 2= mean(ranom number come from second gamma)^2/ var(ranom number come from second gamma)

Comment: @SoadM.Bakry I think what are describing is the computation of so-called "responsibility" of each mixture component for each datum. This is (if I remember correctly) the E part of an EM algorithm. A web search for "expectation maximization algorithm" should turn up a lot of hits.